# Access denied error in Build definition. Build is successfull when server restarted

Tags: azure-pipelines, tfsbuild

### [error]Access to the path 'C:\agent_work\2\s\drop\Release_2015' is denied.

IF I delete the agent folder '2' and restart the server then the build works fine. Again the later Builds ended up with this error message.

Could not find the cause. Any help would be good. Thank you.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Could you share your build definition and entire build log? Do you have other build or process access the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following items:

1. Set the `Clean` option to `True`in the build definition.
2. If you use MSBuild to build your poject, add parameter `/m:1` to use only one processor.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/building-multiple-projects-in-parallel-with-msbuild?view=vs-2019